# How do I run Ethernet off of a router connected to a DSL port

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, dsl

As the title suggests, I’ve grabbed a secondary router and plugged it in my room’s DSL port in hopes of getting an Ethernet connection out of it.

Whenever its connected, the main router in my home goes down briefly (mostly with an invalid IP address or similar error), before restarting itself and everything returns to normal, meanwhile the secondary router gets no internet connection at all.

At first I thought it was an IP conflict, so I changed the IP of my secondary router to match the primary, but to no avail, in the user interface its saying that DSL is being interrupted and its most likely due to my ISP.

Ive contacted them and it seems that everything is normal on their end too; if anyone has any ideas as to why this is or just tips in setting up 2 routers in general it’d be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `1` If you are trying to use the router as a switch make sure DHCP is disabled and all physical connections are made to and from the LAN ports (not WAN). `2` update your question with the router make and model. `3` Explain what you mean by *"my room's DSLport"* what is that where does it go.

Comment: You cannot have multiple devices connected to the same DSL line.